# Make div with bottom triangle

Tags: html, css, geometry, css-shapes

I have been trying to do the **white shape** with a div:

http://sircat.net/joomla/sircat/mies/2.png

how do I get the diagonal shapes of the bottom of the div?

I have this for the div:
    width: 620px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: white;

thank you

Edit: just forget the bg behind the div, I want to make the div with the diagonal borders, not with the help of the bg because it is in the top layer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use borders and the `:after` pseudo selector: http://jsfiddle.net/qQySU/

```
#pointed {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
}

#pointed:after,
#pointed::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 150px red;
    border-left: solid 100px transparent;
    border-right: solid 100px transparent;
}
```

I've colored the tip for easy identification of the borders. Play around the border widths on the last 3 lines to get the tip you want.

**Edit.:**

Reference for compability: http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent

**Edit 2:**

In exchange for semantics, you can get it more crossbrowser you can place the stle on a inner element instead of on the `:after` pseudo selector.

Comment: This would prevent you from continuing the text over the triangle.

Comment: Not if you position it outside of the content and use other container over it to keep the text.

Answer (score 5):

**Simplest (least amount of code)** method: just use a CSS [**`linear-gradient`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient) http://dabblet.com/gist/3610406

HTML:

```
<div class='box'>Text goes here...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 26em;
    min-height: 31em;
    padding: 1em;
    outline: solid 1px lightblue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, dimgrey 47%, black 50%, transparent 50%) 
                    no-repeat 0 100%, 
                linear-gradient(-45deg, dimgrey 47%, black 50%, transparent 50%) 
                    no-repeat 100% 100%;;
    background-size: 50% 14em;
}
```

---

**Better compatibility & better looking**: you could use a [**pseudo-element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-elements) with a [**`box-shadow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow): http://dabblet.com/gist/3610548

HTML:

```
<div class='box'>text goes here... hover me ;)</div>
```

CSS:

```
html { background: darkgrey; }
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 3em auto 0;
    background: white;
}
.box:before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 14.65%; /* 50% - 35.35% */ bottom: -35.35%; /* half of 70.71% */
    width: 70.71%; /* 100%*sqrt(2)/2 */
    height: 70.71%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px dimgrey;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: white;
    content: '';
}
.box:hover, .box:hover:before {
    background: plum;
}
```

Comment: **Thank you** for introducing me to [dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com). I don't know why anyone would use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for CSS-only demos when there's a much neater alternative :)