# CSS title with triangle bottom shape

Tags: css

im straggling to create such title style in CSS. Can someone help me please?

[image]

Comment: here is starting template: https://jsfiddle.net/d49gw21y/

Comment: This won't work without using SVG, specialized PNG images or canvas

Comment: This can be done in CSS by turning a div into a triangle and then fixing it to the bottom of the header. The header text can then be positioned over this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12251346/2506219 on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally possible with following css

```
.content::after{
    content: "";
    background: #fff;
    transform: skewY(10deg);
    width: 50%;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 75px;
}
.content::before{
    content: "";
    background: #fff;
    transform: skewY(-10deg);
    width: 50%;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 75px;
}

.content{
  width:100%;
  height:75px;
  background:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:20px;
}
```

you should check it on different screen sizes and tweak with height of after and before elements
In this case content class should be element you want to add triangle